# How to set Customized Type Mappings in JDBC when using collection pool?

Tags: java, jdbc, bonecp

How can I set [Customized Type Mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html) in JDBC when using collection pool ? I'm using BoneCP. Calling `getTypeMap/setTypeMap` ever time I get `Connection` object is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: You might be able to use [`ConnectionHook`](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/com/jolbox/bonecp/hooks/ConnectionHook.html) with the `onAcquire()` or `onCheckOut()`. Not sure though, so I am just commenting instead of answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible therefore I had to modify MySql Java Connector to support UUID type.

If anyone knows better solution please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use an ORM, [sormula](http://www.sormula.org) makes custom types easy with [TypeTranslator](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/translator/TypeTranslator.html). See the org.sormula.tests.translator.* packages for examples.